# CheckedTextView in LinearLayout

Tags: android, xml

I have the bellow xml. I would like to make the imageview clickable. However, it appears that i can only click the checkedTextView. Is there a way where i can have the checkedtextview as well as the imageview independently clickable? It seems like the checkedTextView is consuming the entire space, with the imageview behind the checkedtextview (maybe?). Any ideas? Pretty new to android development, and this has be very confused. I attempted giving weights, but it didn't seem to help at all.

```
 <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="60dp" 
            android:orientation="vertical">
        <CheckedTextView
            android:id="@+id/checked_text_view" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" 
            android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple" 
            android:gravity="center_vertical" 
            android:text="@string/hello_world" 
            android:textColor="@color/white" 
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/my_image_pencil" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/image_pencil" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do you need it horizontaly?

Comment: @PiyushGupta yeah, its a row in a list =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this one...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="60dp" >

 <CheckedTextView
    android:id="@+id/checked_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
    android:gravity="center|right"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:text="Hello"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/my_image_pencil"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

If you want to click event of ImageView in your row item then set

```
android:focusable="false
```

for your ***CheckedTextView***.

Comment: hmm well it made the layout of each row in the list look nicer. but i can still only select the checkedTextView. thanks for trying to help me though.

Comment: no luck still! I donno why nothing is working =/ thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
   <LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="60dp" 
        android:orientation="vertical">
<CheckedTextView
    android:id="@+id/checked_text_view" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" 
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple" 
    android:gravity="center_vertical" 
    android:text="@string/hello_world" 
    android:textColor="@color/white" 
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/my_image_pencil" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onclick="onImageClick" 
        android:src="@drawable/image_pencil" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In the activity have a method like this

```
public void onImageClick(View view)
{
  // handler for imageclick
}
```

Comment: hmmm no luck :( still the same

Answer (score 0):

As when we use checkboxes, button, imagebutton etc in list view. It takes all focus of listview, And thus when we click on the listview or other elements of listview like images etc, then there is no any focus on these widgets, And thus no clickable action perform on them.

So just change your code for checkbox like following..

```
<CheckedTextView
            android:id="@+id/checked_text_view" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" 
            android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple" 
            android:gravity="center_vertical" 
            android:text="@string/hello_world"  
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
```

I just added in your code this line..
**`android:focusable="false`**

Comment: no luck. for some reason the entire row is still consumed by the checkedtextview and hence it's the only thing that i can select.. =/ thanks anyway though

Comment: Like you are using imageview and checkbox in particular listitem, then add android:focusable="true" to the imageview, may be then the focus on your imageview comes. This error comes due to the focus. you can try this, it may be work.